# In this model extension ever holds CH

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal and consider the collapsing forcing $\mathbb{P}:=Coll(\omega_1,<\kappa)$. I know that for every generic extension $V^{\mathbb{P}}$ we get $\kappa=\aleph_2$. But, is it true that $V^{\mathbb{P}}\models CH$?

If the answer is negative. Which combinatorics properties we need to assume in $V$ to get a counter example?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

1. You are not adding any new reals since your forcing is $\sigma$-closed.
2. Whatever the continuum was in the ground model, it was *well*-below $\kappa$, so it must have collapsed to $\omega_1$ in the process.

$\sf 1+2 = CH$.

(Note that we don't *really* need that $\kappa$ is measurable, just larger than the continuum.)

Comment: Yes, apparently $\sf CH=3$.

Comment: Who knew? :) ....

Comment: If I had to guess? Saharon Shelah.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course! I didn't have in mind that my forcig is $\sigma$-closed. Also, it's interesting how you collapse the continuum until be a finite cardinal.

Comment: @Gödel: Well, I'm not claiming that CH implies that $2^{\aleph_0}=3$, since everyone knows that $\aleph_0=3$ and $2^{\aleph_0}=4$ (note, CH holds, there are no cardinals between 3 and 4). I merely claimed that CH itself, the statement, equals 3.

Comment: Fun times on Math Stack Exchange, @AsafKaragila! :)

Comment: @paul: If it wasn't fun, I wouldn't be here. :)